# Get TLD from email in mssql without tsql

Tags: sql-server

Is there a simple solution to get the top level domain (TLD) from a e-mail address?

It's important, that TLDs like `.berlin` and Subdomains like `info@infrastructure.bdata.de` are also supported.

No TSQL, just one single query is possible.

Comment: "No TSQL, just one single query is possible" - all queries in SQL Server are written in T-SQL - T-SQL is Microsoft's SQL dialect. What is your *real* constraint? No UDFs? No SPRocs?

Comment: Just without variables or loops, so that it can be used in a simple select-statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example. Replace the example e-mail address with your real e-mail address:

```
Select  substring(   'mike.meyer@infrastructure.bdata.berlin'    , 1 + 1+  LEN('mike.meyer@infrastructure.bdata.berlin') -  CHARINDEX('.' , reverse('mike.meyer@infrastructure.bdata.berlin')) , LEN('mike.meyer@infrastructure.bdata.berlin')    )
```

The problem is, charindex() returns only the first character, but we need the last one. So we also need reverse().

The statement does the following steps:

1. Reverse the string and get the last `.`
2. Then we need substring. First parameter is the full string without reverse, second parameter is the start parameter. It's calcuated with the full length - length of the TLD. It's required to add +1 for the `.` and a second +1 for the start index of substring in mssql.
3. That's it!